# find the mean, minimum and maximum amount for a text file data in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find the **mean**, **minimum** and **maximum** amount for a text file data by using python 3.4.

The input text file contains two numbers:

- The first denotes the day and is an integer starting from zero
- The second is the reading of the generation meter at the end of that day.

Note that there is not a reading for every day in the file and some lines in the file start with `#` and are to be interpreted as comments.

In order to find the mean, minimum and maximum amount per day I used the following code, but it doesn’t work properly as the splitted list contains `#` and others comments.

Is there anyone who can suggest me an appropriate way to remove the unwanted part?  Or can suggest me the appropriate way to find the mean, minimum and maximum amount per day.

The code is as follows:

```
import sys, math, pylab
with open('generation.dat') as f:

for line in f:
    parts = line.split()            # Will split line into parts
    if len(parts) > 1:              # if at least 2 columns
        days = parts[0]             # first line denotes the day
        readings = parts[1]         # second line is the reading of the generation meter at the end of the day
        #days.remove(#)
        #readings.remove(Day, holiday)

        #d = int(days)
        #r = float (readings)
        print (days, readings)      # print columns

amounts = [ readings[i] - readings[i-1] for i in range(1, len(readings))


print ("Mean amount generated per day is:", (sum(amounts) / len(amounts)))
print ("Minimum amount generated per day is:", min(amounts))
print ("Maximum amount generated per day is:", max(amounts))
```

Text file contains below-mentioned data

```
# Day zero is 30 xi 2011
0 99.5
# xii 2011
1 102.1
2 109.9
3 116.5
4 117.7
5 124.2
6 131.6
7 140.9
8 141.7
9 151
10 158.2
11 158.8
12 167.6
13 175
14 179.3
15 183.2
16 183.7
17 190.4
18 195
19 195.7
20 200
21 200.9      shortest day
```

After using the above-mentioned code output is showing like below:

```
# Day
0 99.5
# xii
1 102.1
2 109.9
3 116.5
4 117.7
5 124.2
6 131.6
7 140.9
8 141.7
9 151
10 158.2
11 158.8
12 167.6
13 175
14 179.3
15 183.2
16 183.7
17 190.4
18 195
19 195.7
20 200
21 200.9
```

Comment: The `days` and `readings` are scalar in your code so they will only retain a single value at the end of the loop. Declare them as lists (`days = []`, `reaadings= []`) and then instead of `readings =  part[0]` use `readings.append(part[0])`. And change the print statement accordingly inside the loop.

Comment: Also unless this is homework or for your own learning, you should really use something like the `csv` module and/or numpy arrays with `loadtxt`/`genfromtxt` or pandas for large and complicated datasets. These should be able to better parse the data and remove comment lines and make the calculations considerably easier and faster.

Comment: @ SigmaPiEpsilon: Can you explain it more (“Declare them as lists (days = [], reaadings= []) and then instead of readings = part[0] use readings.append(part[0])”)? I am new in Python. It would be really great for me if you give an example to do it by using the code that I have mentioned earlier.

Comment: Since you already accepted an answer I assume you solved your problem. What I meant was in your code `days` and `readings` store only a single value. Each time loop is run this value gets overwritten. If you want to get all the values you need to define them as list and append the values to them. Then you can use a line like `amounts = [ readings[i] - readings[i-1] for i in range(1, len(readings))` which assumes `readings` is a list.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I got it. Actually, I wanted to see the result as a list. Finally, it is working properly. I have updated my code according to your instruction. Also, i have used "line = line.split('#')[0]" to omit the unnecessary comments. The output is okay and I can proceed to the next steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wants to skip comments lines (starting by `#`) just replace

```
if len(parts) > 1:
```

By:

```
if len(parts) > 1 and not line.startswith('#'):
```

---

If you wants to remove all comments within each lines just add

```
line = line.split('#')[0]
```

Before line `parts = line.split()`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I am trying to find the difference between two readings of the second column. The code is as follows. "amounts = [ r[i] - r[i-1] for i in range(1, len(r)) ]". But i am getting an error msg like "TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()". So why i am getting this error. and how to solve it? Do I need to convert the second line into an array. If yes then how to do that?

Comment: In `amounts = [ r[i] - r[i-1] for i in range(1, len(r)) ]` the part `len(r)` ask for length of variable `r`. Float variables didn't have length, only iterables like lists and dicts. Maybe you wants `int(r)`?

Comment: Actually, I wanted to get the output as a list. The problem has been solved. Now I can start the next part of the program. Thanks a lot for your help.